# Git 403 for wrong user

Tags: git, github

When I push a new repo to GitHub, it is picking up the wrong name...

```
> ControlDemo (master)$ git push -u origin master remote: Permission to
> JohnLivermore/XamarinFormsControlDemo.git denied to jelwp. fatal:
> unable to access
> 'https://github.com/JohnLivermore/XamarinFormsControlDemo.git/': The
> requested URL returned error: 403
```

I checked my .gitconfig and my {projectfolder}/.git/config, but I am not seeing the offending user (jelwp) anywhere in those files.  Also, the correct user is in the [user] section of my .gitconfig.

What else could cause this to happen?

Comment: If you're on windows I would make sure your credentials are as expected in credentials manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: how did you fixed it?